I want to drag a custom class to a map to add an annotation
I want to drag and drop a custom class object from a popover view onto a map view. I have the object dragging correctly, but the map isn't accepting the drop.
Here's my custom class:
class Marker: Codable, Identifiable, Transferable {
    
    public var uuid: UUID
    public var type: MarkerType
    public var latitude: Double?
    public var longitude: Double?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case uuid
        case type
        case latitude
        case longitude
    }
    
    public func encode(to encoder: any Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(uuid, forKey: .uuid)
        try container.encode(type, forKey: .type)
        try container.encode(latitude, forKey: .latitude)
        try container.encode(longitude, forKey: .longitude)
    }
    
    public required init(from decoder: any Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.uuid = try container.decodeIfPresent(UUID.self, forKey: .uuid) ?? UUID()
        self.type = try container.decode(MarkerType.self, forKey: .type)
        self.latitude = try container.decodeIfPresent(Double.self, forKey: .latitude) ?? 0
        self.longitude = try container.decodeIfPresent(Double.self, forKey: .longitude) ?? 0
    }
    
    init(type: MarkerType, latitude: Double? = 0, longitude: Double? = 0) {
        self.uuid = UUID()
        self.type = type
        self.latitude = latitude ?? 0
        self.longitude = longitude ?? 0
    }
    
    static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
        CodableRepresentation(contentType: .content)
    }
}

Here's my map view:
            Map(
                coordinateRegion: $locationManager.region,
                showsUserLocation: true,
                annotationItems: model.markers) { marker in
                    mark(for: marker)
                }
                .task {
                    refreshMarkers()
                }
                .dropDestination(for: Marker.self) { items, location in
                    let marker = items[0]
                    marker.latitude = location.x //CONVERT TO MAP LATITUDE
                    marker.longitude = location.y //CONVERT TO MAP LONGITUDE
                    model.markers.append(items[0])
                    print("Dropped \(marker) at \(location)")
                    return true
                }
        }

Can anyone help me understand why my map isn't taking the drop?

Observations, re-structure your code to use the more modern approach
using MapKit for SwiftUI (Map with a closure),
see also Map.
Note, Map already has a Marker, rename yours (eg MyMarker)
and importantly use struct MyMarker: Codable, Identifiable,... with
a let id = UUID() for Identifiable. No need for the
func encode(to ... and init(from decoder:.. stuff.
Show a complete example code that can be compiled and run to reproduce your problem.
